# Buscar email na base de dados através do nome

Tags: c#

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tenho todos os clientes inseridos na `listbox1` mas eu por exemplo só quero selecionar alguns, e esses vão para a `listbox2`.

Na `listbox2` tenho o id e o nome dos clientes e, ao carregar no botão "enviar email", preciso que vá automaticamente buscar os emails destes.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    System.Net.NetworkCredential smtpCreds = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("meu mail", "Minha pass");

    try
    {
        cliente.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        cliente.Port = 587;
        cliente.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        cliente.Credentials = smtpCreds;
        cliente.EnableSsl = true;

        string body = string.Concat("Nome: ", txtnome.Text, "\nE-Mail:", txtemail.Text, "\nMensagem", txtmsg.Text);
        msg.Subject = "fale connosco";
        msg.Body = body;
        msg.From = new MailAddress("MEU EMAIL");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("AJUDA!"));
        cliente.Send(msg);

        label6.Text = "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
    }
    catch
    {
        label6.Text = "Erro ao enviar E-mail";
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui graças a um amigo e por isso deixo aqui a resposta

```
 int numclientes = listBox2.Items.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < numclientes; i++)
            {
                string destinatario = listBox2.Items[i].ToString();
                string[] words = destinatario.Split('-');


                String Query = "SELECT email FROM cliente where Cod_Cliente=" + words[0];
                SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, cn);
                SqlDataReader myreader;

                try
                {

                    cn.Open();
                    myreader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                    while (myreader.Read())
                    {
                        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(myreader.GetString(0)));
                        cliente.Send(msg);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                cn.Close();
```

Comment: E estes e-mails estão aonde? Em um banco de dados? Qual a estrutura das tabelas? Que banco que é? Qual tecnologia esta usando para fazer o acesso?

Comment: Você colocou o código menos relevante para ajudar a solucionar sua dúvida. Por favor, mostre como está populando suas listbox's e as informações do banco conforme comentário acima.

Comment: ajuda o print das tabelas?

Comment: @FabioGonçalves Não. Precisamos saber como estes e-mails estão gravados. Precisamos de um exemplo de como buscar estes e-mails na sua base de dados. Pode por favor editar sua pergunta novamente?

Comment: como assim?
os emails tao gravados na table cliente, sao ai gravados...com a query Select email from cliente eu tenho acesso aos emails mas o que eu preciso e mais complexo do que isso

Comment: Você quer por exemplo `Nome = Joao`, busque na base de dados o email do `Joao`? Já tento fazer algo? Como é a `Estrutura` da tabela que está armazenando os `emails`?

Comment: Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar mas ja consegui resolver o problema :D

Comment: Olá mortal @FabioGonçalves, tem como colocar a resposta para que futuros mortais com o mesmo problema possam resolve-los também?

Comment: Olá Fábio, coloque a sua resposta como uma resposta e não na própria pergunta. Assim fica tudo certinho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas formatando a resposta já fornecida em pergunta com algumas modificações, como a abertura e o fechamento da *connection* fora do `for`:

```
int numclientes = listBox2.Items.Count;
cn.Open();
for (int i = 0; i < numclientes; i++)
    {
        string destinatario = listBox2.Items[i].ToString();
        string[] words = destinatario.Split('-');


        String Query = "SELECT email FROM cliente where Cod_Cliente=" + words[0];
        SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, cn);
        SqlDataReader myreader;

        try
        {
            myreader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myreader.Read())
            {
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(myreader.GetString(0)));
                cliente.Send(msg);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

cn.Close();
```